# Does Boto3 DynamoDB have reserved attribute names for update_item with conditions expressions? Unexpected attribute SET behavior

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I've implemented a simple object versioning scheme that allows the calling code to supply a `current_version` integer that that will set the `ConditionExpression`. I've also implemented a simple timestamping scheme to set an attribute named `auto_timestamp` to the current unix timestamp.

When the `ConditionExpression` is supplied with the object's current version integer, the update occurs, but also sets `auto_timestamp` to the current version value, rather than the value supplied in `ExpressionAttributeValues`. This only occurs if the attribute names are `#a0`, `#a1` ... and values are `:v0`, `:v1` ...

For example, this runs as expected without the condition, and `auto_timestamp` is set to `1643476414` in the table. The `if_not_exists` is used to start the object version at 0 if the item does not yet exist or did not previously have a `auto_object_version` attribute.

```py
update_kwargs = {
    "Key": {"user_id": user_id},
    "UpdateExpression": 'SET #a0 = :v0, #a1 = if_not_exists(#a1, :zero) + :v1',
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#a0": "auto_timestamp", "#a1": "auto_object_version"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":v0": 1643476414, ":v1": 1, ":zero": 0}
}
table.update_item(**update_kwargs)
```

However, this example runs without exception, but `auto_timestamp` is set to `1`. This behavior continues for each subsequent increment of `current_version` for additional calls to `update_item`

```py
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
update_kwargs = {
    "Key": {"user_id": user_id},
    "UpdateExpression": 'SET #a0 = :v0, #a1 = if_not_exists(#a1, :zero) + :v1',
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#a0": "auto_timestamp", "#a1": "auto_object_version"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":v0": 1643476414, ":v1": 1, ":zero": 0}
    "ConditionExpression": Attr("auto_object_version").eq(1)
}
table.update_item(**update_kwargs)
```

While debugging, I changed the scheme by which I am labeling the attribute names and values to use `#att` instead of `#a` and `:val` instead of `:v` and the following works as desired and `auto_timestamp` is set to `1643476414`:

```py
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Attr
update_kwargs = {
    "Key": {"user_id": user_id},
    "UpdateExpression": 'SET #att0 = :val0, #att1 = if_not_exists(#att1, :zero) + :val1',
    "ExpressionAttributeNames": {"#att0": "auto_timestamp", "#att1": "auto_object_version"},
    "ExpressionAttributeValues": {":val0": 1643476414, ":val1": 1, ":zero": 0}
    "ConditionExpression": Attr("auto_object_version").eq(1)
}
table.update_item(**update_kwargs)
```

I couldn't find any documentation on reserved attribute names or values that shouldn't be used for keys in `ExpressionAttributeNames` or `ExpressionAttributeValues`.

Is this behavior anyone has witnessed before? The behavior is easily worked around when switching the string formatting used to generate the keys but was very unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

There are no reserved attribute or value names, and I routinely use names like `:v1` and `#a1` in my own tests, and they seem to work fine.

Assuming you correctly copied-pasted your code into the question, it seems to me you simply have a syntax error in your code - you are missing a double-quote after the `"auto_timestamp`. What I don't understand, though, is how this compiles or why changing a to att changed anything. Please be more careful in pasting a self-contained code snippet that works or doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I did not directly copy/paste the code from my app, since there's a number of layers of abstraction - I've implemented a sort of generic repository layer on top of boto3. I copied the values from the debugger into a readable sample and made a typo. I will work on producing an actual script that will run to reproduce the issue.